# How to populate dynamic navigation menu list following my table structures using php(codeigniter) and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, navigation

I am trying to generate dynamic multi-level navigation list for one of my web application.
In the application there will be different roles for different type of members. So each member will have his own multi-level menu list depending on the role. 
To populate dynamic navigation menu lists there are following tables:

MEMBERS_MENU TABLE: (In this table all members are set up with their relevant menu list)  -->(first image)

NAVIGATION_MENU_LINK TABLE: (In this table there is the link between the parent menu and child menu)-->(second image)

PARENT_MENU TABLE: (To define parent menu) --> (third image)

CHILD_MENU TABLE: (To define child menu) --> (fourth image)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am building dynamic navigation menu for different type of users for my web application.
I want to display the navigation menu for

**MEMBER_ID 1:**

NEWS

```
-- ALL

-- PREVIEW

-- SUMMARY
```

AUDIO

```
-- PREVIEW
```

VIDEO

```
-- ALL
```

**MEMBER_ID 2:**

NEWS

```
-- ALL

-- PREVIEW
```

AUDIO

```
-- PREVIEW
```

VIDEO

```
-- ALL
```

**MEMBER_ID 3:**

AUDIO

```
-- PREVIEW
```

VIDEO

```
-- ALL
```

I have been trying several hours to populate MULTI-LEVEL NAVIGATION MENU LIST using the above database table structures. I am trying to populate dynamic menu-list using FOREACH LOOP and have coded in codeigniter and mysql. 
But it is not generating the menu list as above example?

If anyone can come up with efficient code example following the above database table structures will be appreciated.

Advance thanks for your comments, codes.

Comment: The way you structure your data and the necessary sql will determine whether you can do this or not. Google 'Joe Celko sql for smarties' as this talks, and demonstrates, the structures that you need.

Comment: jeff ..thanks. i have written the query and can get the value as a two dimensional array. i am struggling to display it as dynamic multi-level navigation list. any suggestion seeing my above table structures?