# Create multi level menus from dynamic two dimensional arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to create multi level menus from the following output from mysql table and php.

This is my code:

```
    $data['menu_response'] = $this->mmenus->getAllMenus($mem_id);

    $array = array();
    $sub_array = array();

    foreach ($data['menu_response'] as $v1) {
        $array[] = $v1->MenuName;
        $sub_array[] = $v1->SubMenuName;
        //print_r($v1->SubMenuName . "</br>");
        //print_r($v1->MenuName . "</br>");
    }

    print_r($array);
    print_r($sub_array);
```

I am getting the printed output as

```
Array ( [0] => News [1] => News [2] => News [3] => Video [4] => Video [5] => Audio ) Array ( [0] => All [1] => Summary [2] => Preview [3] => Summary [4] => Preview [5] => Summary )
```

Here first array is the parent array and the second array is the child array.

The db query is :

> `SELECT prm_members_menus.id,
>   prm_linked_menus.menuLinkedID,prm_linked_menus.menuID,
>   prm_linked_menus.SubMenuID,
>           (SELECT prm_menus.name from prm_menus 
>             where prm_menus.id = prm_linked_menus.menuID) as MenuName ,
>           (SELECT prm_sub_menus.name from prm_sub_menus 
>             where prm_sub_menus.subMenuID = prm_linked_menus.subMenuID) as SubMenuName 
>                 from prm_members_menus 
>                 inner join prm_linked_menus on prm_linked_menus.menuLinkedID = prm_members_menus.menuLinkedID
>                 WHERE prm_members_menus.mem_id=2 
>           order by prm_members_menus.id`

How multi-level menu can be generated from the above output for common parent?

I am building dynamic navigation menu for different type of users for my web application.
I want to display the navigation menu for

```
**MEMBER_ID 1:**

NEWS

    -- ALL

    -- PREVIEW

    -- SUMMARY

AUDIO

    -- PREVIEW 

VIDEO

    -- ALL

**MEMBER_ID 2:**

NEWS

    -- ALL

    -- PREVIEW

AUDIO

    -- PREVIEW 

VIDEO

    -- ALL



**MEMBER_ID 3:**

AUDIO

    -- PREVIEW 

VIDEO

    -- ALL
```

I have been trying several hours to populate MULTI-LEVEL NAVIGATION MENU LIST using the above database table structures. I am trying to populate dynamic menu-list and it's href, icon using FOREACH LOOP and have coded in codeigniter and mysql.

Darren has helped to generate the parent, sub menu list.

Now the next problem to change the Menu, SubMenu href, icon dynamically from the returned query along with the MenuName, SubMenuName. How can it be achieved?

<<<

the PHP output of the mysql query:

```
  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 10 [menuLinkedID] => 1 [menuID] => 2 [SubMenuID] => 1 [MenuName] => News [SubMenuName] => All ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 11 [menuLinkedID] => 2 [menuID] => 2 [SubMenuID] => 2 [MenuName] => News [SubMenuName] => Summary ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [menuLinkedID] => 3 [menuID] => 2 [SubMenuID] => 3 [MenuName] => News [SubMenuName] => Preview ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 14 [menuLinkedID] => 5 [menuID] => 3 [SubMenuID] => 2 [MenuName] => Video [SubMenuName] => Summary ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 15 [menuLinkedID] => 6 [menuID] => 3 [SubMenuID] => 3 [MenuName] => Video [SubMenuName] => Preview ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 17 [menuLinkedID] => 8 [menuID] => 4 [SubMenuID] => 2 [MenuName] => Audio [SubMenuName] => Summary ) )
```

the UPDATED PHP output of the query to fetch MenuName, SubMenuName, href, icon :

THE QUERY IS:
...............

> `SELECT prm_members_menus.id, prm_linked_menus.menuLinkedID,prm_linked_menus.menuID, prm_linked_menus.SubMenuID,
>   prm_menus.href as parent_href,prm_menus.i_class as parent_i_class,prm_sub_menus.href as child_href,prm_sub_menus.i_class as child_i_class,
>           (SELECT prm_menus.name from prm_menus 
>               where prm_menus.id = prm_linked_menus.menuID) as MenuName ,
>           (SELECT prm_sub_menus.name from prm_sub_menus 
>               where prm_sub_menus.subMenuID = prm_linked_menus.subMenuID) as SubMenuName 
>                   from prm_members_menus 
>                   inner join prm_linked_menus on prm_linked_menus.menuLinkedID = prm_members_menus.menuLinkedID
>                   inner join prm_menus on prm_menus.id = prm_linked_menus.menuID
>                   inner join prm_sub_menus on prm_sub_menus.subMenuID = prm_linked_menus.subMenuID
>                   WHERE prm_members_menus.mem_id= 2
>           order by prm_members_menus.id`

OUTPUT IS:
..............

```
  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [menuLinkedID] => 1 [menuID] => 2 [SubMenuID] => 1 [parent_href] => news [parent_i_class] => fa fa-list-alt [child_href] => all [child_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [MenuName] => News [SubMenuName] => All ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [menuLinkedID] => 2 [menuID] => 2 [SubMenuID] => 2 [parent_href] => news [parent_i_class] => fa fa-list-alt [child_href] => summary [child_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [MenuName] => News [SubMenuName] => Summary ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [menuLinkedID] => 3 [menuID] => 2 [SubMenuID] => 3 [parent_href] => news [parent_i_class] => fa fa-list-alt [child_href] => preview [child_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [MenuName] => News [SubMenuName] => Preview ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [menuLinkedID] => 4 [menuID] => 3 [SubMenuID] => 1 [parent_href] => video [parent_i_class] => fa fa-eye [child_href] => all [child_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [MenuName] => Video [SubMenuName] => All ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [menuLinkedID] => 6 [menuID] => 3 [SubMenuID] => 3 [parent_href] => video [parent_i_class] => fa fa-eye [child_href] => preview [child_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [MenuName] => Video [SubMenuName] => Preview ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [menuLinkedID] => 7 [menuID] => 4 [SubMenuID] => 1 [parent_href] => audio [parent_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [child_href] => all [child_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [MenuName] => Audio [SubMenuName] => All ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [menuLinkedID] => 8 [menuID] => 4 [SubMenuID] => 2 [parent_href] => audio [parent_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [child_href] => summary [child_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [MenuName] => Audio [SubMenuName] => Summary ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 8 [menuLinkedID] => 9 [menuID] => 4 [SubMenuID] => 3 [parent_href] => audio [parent_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [child_href] => preview [child_i_class] => fa fa-folder-o [MenuName] => Audio [SubMenuName] => Preview ) )
```

Comment: Where is the code for creating the menus? You've just dumped out the data structure in the code you've posted.

Comment: i am trying to generate the parent menus and the sub-child menus from the above data structure. I don't have the code to create menus thats why given the db structure and the trying foreach loop code. please also have a look into my last similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226585/how-to-populate-dynamic-navigation-menu-list-following-my-table-structures-using

Comment: It would be more informative to give a var_dump of $data['menu_response'] rather than give us a database query.  I assume your problem is with the PHP, not the database design or database query, correct?  The DB is irrelevant in this case - just show us the php array you're getting from the DB and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @airtech can you please have a look on the updated question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you're seperating the Parent level menu and the sub menu, how do you know which sub menus belong to which menu?

You should change your menu assigning to something like this:

```
$menu = array();
foreach ($data['menu_response'] as $v1) {
    $menu[$v1->MenuName][] = $v1->SubMenuName;
}
```

Which would technically give you something like:

```
Array (
    [Menu-item] => Array(
        [0] => [Sub-menu-item],
        [2] => [Sub-menu-item],
    )
.....etc
)
```

That way you can just simply loop through the `$menu` array and print it out in the structure you want.

Example:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($menu as $title => $submenu) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $title;
    if(!empty($submenu)) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($submenu as $item) {
            echo "<li>{$item}</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "<li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

---

Updated answer:
You'd just create an associative array like I stated in the comments :)
A simple loop like this should do:

```
$menu = array();
foreach ($data['menu_response'] as $v1) {
    $menu[$v1->MenuName][] = array('submenu' => $v1->SubMenuName, 'icon' => $v1->child_i_class);
}
```

And you can print that out like this:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($menu as $title => $submenu) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $title;
    if(!empty($submenu)) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($submenu as $item) {
            echo "<li><i class='{$item['icon']}'></i> {$item['submenu']}</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "<li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Hi Darren, many thanks. You're answer is perfectly correct for me. I have provided the details in my last question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226585/how-to-populate-dynamic-navigation-menu-list-following-my-table-structures-using

Comment: In addition to last comment..I have 4 tables. table 1 for members_menu -- this table will store all the members menus and their link-menus ID. table 2 for link-menus; here the parent menus, child menus are linked. I will store the LinkID in to the members_menu table. third table is for storing the parent menus and final table 4 for storing the sub menus. The parent menuID and the subMenuID will stored in the LinkMenu table.  Again many thanks for reply.

Comment: I am really very happy about your answer! It solved my problem. That 2 dimensional array i tried to populate in many alternative ways..but failed every time!I have just integrated your solution to my web app and it is displaying the menu exactly the way i wanted :)

Comment: @techhunter Sweet! I'm glad that helped you! This is exactly what communities like SO are for. Always get a different alternative to how you think stuff should be done :)

Comment: true. what do think about my logical db structure? will it help to populate dynamic multi level menus depending on the role id or member type in a system?

Comment: Hi @Darren i want to change the Menu href, icon dynamically fetching this information from the db table. How can i get the menu href, icon information?

Comment: the array is returning that value. please have a look in to my updated second query.                                     foreach ($data['menu_response'] as $v1) {
    $menu[$v1->MenuName][] = $v1->SubMenuName;
}

Comment: @techhunter Hi mate, you just need to create an associative array and when you print out the menu, you echo the icon out

Comment: thanks mate. I tried to create the associative array with MenuName and the icon. But it was not created for the above query. If you can have a look and provide an updated code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ..thanks mate. My problem is almost fixed. One last issue about the main menu icon. I also want to add the icon of the Parent Main Menu. So do i have to change the array as : $menu[$v1->MenuName, $v1->parent_i_class][] =  array('submenu' => $v1->SubMenuName, 'icon' => $v1->child_i_class); ??

Comment: `foreach ($data['menu_response'] as $v1) {
$menu[$v1->MenuName]['icon'] = $v1->parent_i_class;    
$menu[$v1->MenuName][] = array('submenu' => $v1->SubMenuName, 'icon' => $v1->child_i_class);
}` should do!

Comment: Is it the same code .mate? I just need to get the main menu icon

Comment: No it's changed, you just need to the icon out :)

Comment: Hi mate .. what will be the printed output for main menu icon?

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for ya?

Don't know if you need to create a multidimensional array that you want to print later (aka the reason for $array and $sub_array) or if you just need to display it out.  My assumption is based on your question, you just need to display it and this is a good answer for you.

```
$MenuName = "";
foreach ($data['menu_response'] as $v1) {
    if ($v1->MenuName != $MenuName) {
        // New Main Menu Line
        if ($MenuName != "") {
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        echo "<ul>";
        $MenuName = $v1->MenuName;
        print_main_menu($v1->MenuName);
    }
    print_sub_main_menu($v1->SubMenuName, $v1->menuLinkedID);
}
if ($MenuName != "") {
    echo "</ul>";

print_main_menu($Text) {
    echo "<li>$Text</li>";
}

print_sub_menu($Text, $MenuId) {
    echo "<li><a href=$MenuId>$Text</a></li>";
}
```

Editted to show example of how to append HTML to the items.

Comment: He wants a menu, the example he gave was just how he wanted them set up in the menu. (not literally printed like that). Just a heads up :)

Comment: Hi Darren, you're right. thanks for the comment. Hi airtech you are printing the output .. but i want to display this tree view as multi-level menus. How can i get the main menu values in an one array and the child menus in another array? or is there other way it can be displayed as multi-level menu? can you display this output as navigation link?

Comment: getting this value in foreach loop value from the view i am trying to display it as                                       <li>
       <a class="dropmenu" href=""><i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i><span class="hidden-sm"><?=$value?></span> <span class="badge badge-important">3</span></a>
       <ul>
        <li><a class="submenu" href="page-infrastructure.html"><i class="fa fa-hdd-o"></i><span class="hidden-sm"> <?=$valuee?></span></a></li>        
       </ul> 
      </li>

Comment: That's what I figured - but then why store it in array variables - just print it while you iterate through.  

Basically in the suggestion - you'd just put your html (div tags) along with any css or whatever around the the echo'd info.

Comment: You already have exactly that "the main menu values in an one array and the child menus in another array" in your question in array and sub_array.  That's obviously not what you want.

Comment: yes. i didn't want to have that data in two arrays but i could not figure it out how to represent the array data in a proper way to display navigation menu. Your answer was almost there which Dareen has picked up and corrected what i am looking after. Darren has answered correctly what i am looking after. Please also have a look into my last question.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the code to show just an example of you'd add html before and after.  Didn't figured you'd need that, but alas there ya go in case it helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62638/discussion-between-airtech-and-techhunter).

Comment: Hi @airtech thanks for the chat invitation. your edited answer look like acceptable. But i have already integrated with Darren answer and Darren answer looks perfectly correct, efficient and elegant comapre to your solution. thanks for your attempt and suggestions.  may be in future i will ping-up

Comment: It didn't have anything to do with this particular question - it had information on your database design from your other question.  Eh, whatever - later.